# Creating place names from Latin verbs?

Tags: verbs, noun, neologism

Latin words like crematorium and vomitorium seem to be made from verb + -torium

Is there a pattern to this I can follow for arbitrary verbs?

> [Furor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/furor#Latin) + -torium = furotorium

Or

> [Farcio](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/farcio#Latin) + -torium = Farcitoroum

Or is there something else to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost there, but the -t- belongs to the verb, not suffix. In particular, it's the fourth principle part (the supine/perfect participle) of the verb.

For the verb:

> vomo, vomere, vomui, vomitus (or -um)

Take *vomitum*, drop the *-us*, add the adjectival ending *-orius*, and then use it in the neuter substantively, which yields *vomitorium*.

The respective perfect participial forms for *furor* and *farcio* are *furatus* and *far(c)tus*, which would yield the potential words **furatorium* and **far(c)torium*.